# TYPO3 4.6 include extbase plugin with typoscript

Tags: plugins, typo3, typoscript, extbase

I have TYPO3 4.6, in tempvoila template i have typoscript object path `lib.header` and I want
to redirect output of plugin to `lib.header`
I have extension Gallery and plugin written and configured in ext_localconf.php like this:

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
   $_EXTKEY,
   'RandomPhotoSlideShow',
   array(
       'Photo' => 'randomPhotoSlideShow',
   ),
   // non-cacheable actions
    array(

        'Photo' => ''

    )
);
```

in ext_tables.php like this:

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'RandomPhotoSlideShow',
    'Gets random photos for slide show'
);
```

and in typoscript template I have this:

```
plugin.tx_gallery.widgets {
    papaWidget = USER
    papaWidget {
        userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
       pluginName = RandomPhotoSlideShow
        extensionName = Gallery
        controller = Photo
        action = randomPhotoSlideShow
        switchableControllerActions {
                Photo {
                        1 = randomPhotoSlideShow
                }
        }

        settings =< plugin.tx_gallery.settings
        persistence =< plugin.tx_gallery.persistence
        view =< plugin.tx_gallery.view
        }
}

lib.header < plugin.tx_gallery.widgets.papaWidget
```

But nothing is displayed, could someone please advice where I have mistake or if something changed in extbase 1.4 included in TYPO3 4.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your action. Do you really have a randomPhotoSlideShowAction in your Controller?
Also check if the specified pluginName is correct.

Please try to specify your index or list Action and see what happens.

```
action = index
switchableControllerActions {
    Photo {
        1 = index
    }
}
```

If your action is correct, make sure you are actually returning something from your action!

```
public function randomPhotoSlideShowAction(...) { 

    // [...]

    $this->view->assign('foo', 'bar');

    return $this->view->render();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :), i have randomPhotoSlideShowAction there but i don't give there return value :), now it's all ok, i didn't realize that rendered view must be returned

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, the only thing missing is the `Controller` part (as per naming convention) in

```
controller = PhotoController
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i found here http://www.adick.at/2011-07-01,extbase-plugins-mit-typoscript-einbinden/ and here http://www.adick.at/2011-07-01,extbase-plugins-mit-typoscript-einbinden/ there shouldn't be Controller part also i tried it but without success