# TYPO3 4.7.14 Include Plugin by TypoScript

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase

At first, I have already read the other two Posts.
([Typo3 4.7.2 include extbase plugin via typoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287145/typo3-4-7-2-include-extbase-plugin-via-typoscript) and [Typo3 4.6 include extbase plugin with typoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759942/typo3-4-6-include-extbase-plugin-with-typoscript)) and I also had a look at http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Dispatcher_rework#Dispatcher-rework.

Based on all the Information I linked on top I tried to Include my Plugin by TypoScript.
But I'm still not able to get any output.

I tested the Plugin by inserting it to a Page. (And cleared Cache and typo3temp after my changes)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

My Configuration:

TypoScript:

```
lib.pagelinks = USER
lib.pagelinks {
  userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
  extensionName = UserPagelink
  pluginName = Pi1
  controller = Pagelink
  action = list
  switchableControllerActions {
      Pagelink {
          1 = list
      }
  }
  settings =< plugin.tx_userpagelink.settings
  persistence =< plugin.tx_userpagelink.persistence
  view =< plugin.tx_userpagelink.view
}
```

ext_tables.php:

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::registerPlugin(
  $_EXTKEY,
  'Pi1',
  'Pagelink'
);
```

ext_localconf.php

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
  $_EXTKEY,
  'Pi1',
  array(
    'Pagelink' => 'list, renderLinks',

  ),
  // non-cacheable actions
  array(
    'Pagelink' => 'renderLinks',

  )
);
```

PagelinkController.php (tried with and without return)

```
public function listAction() {
    $pagelinks = $this->pagelinkRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('pagelinks', $pagelinks);
    return $this->view->render();
}
```

Extension Key: user_pagelink

Comment: Whats your extension key? `user_pagelinks`?

Comment: Yes the ext key is user_pagelink (without s)

Comment: @biesior yes it is an extbase extension I just named the Plugin Pi1

Comment: @Tony I reproduced your case (also with your code) without any problems and got response from the `listAction`. Are you using `lib.pagelinks` properly after defining it? ie like: `page = PAGE` next line `page.10 < lib.pagelinks` ? BTW you don't need to use `return` statement in the action as long as you are going to return corresponding view. Connect to the chatroom at: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37473/typo3 and describe your case more

Comment: just found the soution there was a lib between my lib.pagelinks an the template include of it. So i changed my code from `page.10 < lib.foo = lib.pagelinks` to `page.10 < lib.foo < lib.pagelinks` ant now it works fine.
thx to biesior for his inputs.